# Dynamically allocated array with dynamically allocated string elements, using getline()

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

I'm trying to create a dynamically allocated array with dynamically allocated string elements, using `getline()`.

This is my code,

```
char** getWordlist()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen( "Wordlist", "r" );
    if( errno == ENOENT )                   
        fp = fopen( "Wordlist", "w+r" );
    if( !fp ) {
        perror( "Could not open wordlist" );
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int c, fileLines = 0;
do{
    c = fgetc(fp);
    if( c == '\n')
        fileLines++;
} while( c != EOF );
rewind(fp);


char** wordlist = calloc( fileLines, sizeof(char*) );  
for( c = 0; c < fileLines; c++ )
    getline( &wordlist[c], 0, fp );

     printf( "%s", (wordlist[0]) );

fclose(fp);
return wordlist;    
}
```

However, `printf` prints outputs `(null)`, so the strings was never created I think.

> What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your `int main(...);`?

Comment: Why `3` in `printf( "%s", (wordlist[3]) );`?

Comment: Method used to determine `fileLines` will be 1 short if `Wordlist` does not end with `'\n'`.

Comment: I only showed the function, sense in main is of no relevance to the error.

Comment: chux ah, ok i'll try make fileLines = 1; then

Comment: No, that does no seem to be right. The file contains 3 words, if i intialize fileLines = 1; fileLines become 4 after the loop.

Comment: @Eijomjo If file contains 3 words than you  `wordlist[3]` will access index out of bounds and cause **_undefined behaviour_** . You can have valid indices `0 ,1 ,2` not `3`. Don't access index `3` .

Comment: @Eijomjo And this information was necessary and was to be mentioned in question .

Comment: @amayCU, oh sorry that was a typo, i have tried 0, 1 and 2 as well.

Comment: the question is about a runtime problem, therefore the question needs to have (as text in the question) 1) a 'small' compilable/runable program that cleanly compiles and shows the problem, the actual inputs to the program, the expected output and the actual output.  The posted code does not compile, and therefore is not able to display the runtime problem.  Please correct these oversights.

Comment: @user3629249 It compiles for me using linux, though maybe i could be different on other OS's.

Comment: for readability by us humans, please consistently indent the code.  Never use tabs for indenting as every word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.  Suggest 4 spaces for each level of indenting as  that allows several levels across the page and is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.   Indent after every opening brace '{'.  un-indent before every closing brace '}'  separate code blocks (if, else, do...while, while, switch, case, default) by a blank line

Comment: This is a strange problem to want to solve. It's not suitable for any real-world application, and not challenging enough to provoke many thoughts for any studies. It might be far more interesting and insightful if you were to require support for multi-terabyte files... (of course this would mean you'd have to tell us *what you intend to do* with the wordlist)

Comment: @Eijomjo,  After adding these missing statements: `#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>`  then it cleanly compiles.  It still does not link and run

Comment: if the input file does not exist, output the error message (calling perror()) and exit.  Don't bother with a second try to open the file for writing, as the file will be empty and the rest of the code will not work.  I.E. remove these two line: `if( errno == ENOENT )
        fp = fopen( "Wordlist", "w+r" );`

Comment: the call to: `rewind()` does not let the program know if it was successful And was made for tape drives, not hard disks.  Suggest using `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET );`  as the returned value can be checked to assure the operation was successful

Comment: user3629249, I'm sorry i doesn't compile for you. I don't know how to make it run on non Linux machines, sense i don't own one.
The thing with opening up a second time if it doesn't exist is because. If a wordlist does not exist, the program creates one. In the program you add, edit, erase or search for words in the wordlist.

Comment: the `do...while();` loop is checking 'too late' for EOF, Suggest: while( c = getchar() && c != EOF ) { if( '\n' == c )  { filelines++; } }`

Comment: @Seb, no this is just an project for school i'm working on, certainly not real-world application ^^. It's a program where you add, erase, edit or search a words in a wordlist simply. The wordlist is stored in a file, but must be imported into a array, according to the assignment.

Comment: in the posted code, if the file, initially, did not exist, then `filelines` will be 0, and all the call to `calloc()` and after ward should not be executed.  Suggest If file did not exist, return NULL.

Comment: assuming that the input file exists,  The file might not end with a trailing '\n' however, there may be a final line that needs to be counted.

Comment: @Eijomjo Such a shame... This would have been an excellent opportunity for your professor to introduce his/her students to algorithms, and have them develop a trie or hashtable of some description, perhaps even within the file itself...

Comment: the variable `c` is being used for two totally different purposes.  1) to contain the char read from the file and 2) as a loop counter.   In general, it is a bad programming practice to use a variable for multiple purposes.

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for the suggestions! Though this is nothing serious, so i'm fine with it doing what's intended.

Comment: @user3629249 In the world of Unix (which is dominant even in Windows), a line is considered to be a sequence of characters terminated by a newline character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incorrect usage of `getline()`

Pass address of `size_t` rather than `0`.

```
for( c = 0; c < fileLines; c++ )
  // getline( &wordlist[c], 0, fp );
  size_t size = 0;
  getline( &wordlist[c], &size, fp );
```

---

To fix a potential off by 1 in line count calculation

```
int c;
size_t fileLines = 0;
int previous = '\n';
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    if( previous == '\n') fileLines++;
    previous = c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding this line:

```
printf( "%s", (wordlist[3]) );
```

It is trying to print the wrong line. and it is not part of the `for()` loop that is reading the lines from the file.

Suggest:

```
size_t lineLength = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < fileLines; i++ )
{
     getline( &(wordlist[i]), &lineLength, fp );
     printf( "%s\n", wordlist[i] );
}
```